How can I solve the DNS leak when using systemd with DNSOverTLS
The problem:
I am connected to a foreign wifi on Kubuntu Desktop 22.04 and want to configure the DNS system-wide to 9.9.9.9 (quad9) with DNSOverTLS. However, on dnsleaktest.com I still get a different DNS.
I tested with Firefox with "DNS over HTTPS" set to Off.
On https://on.quad9.net I get as expected: YES, You ARE using quad9
On dnsleaktest.com though I get the unexected result:

Here is what I did:
In NetworkManager for the affected wifi, I disabled IPv6 and set IPv4 to Automatic (Only addresses) and put an empty list as DNS server. The resulting configuration in terminal is:
$ nmcli device
DEVICE        TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
wlo1          wifi      connected     TP-LINK_58DE
p2p-dev-wlo1  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --
lo            loopback  unmanaged     --

$ nmcli device show wlo1
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     TP-LINK_58DE
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.112/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

I configured /etc/systemd/resolved.conf as such (only the last few lines are relevant, but for completeness / error checking I provide the full file):
$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the resolved.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# Use 'systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf' to display the full config.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details.

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
#DNSStubListenerExtra=
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
DNS=9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net
FallbackDNS=9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net
Domains=~.
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes

After sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved and sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager, this is the resulting configuration (entire output is pasted here):
$ resolvectl status
Global
           Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=yes/supported
    resolv.conf mode: foreign
  Current DNS Server: 9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net
         DNS Servers: 9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net
Fallback DNS Servers: 9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net
          DNS Domain: ~.

Link 2 (wlo1)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=yes/supported

In basic tests it seems to work:
$ resolvectl query archlinux.com
archlinux.com: 3.64.163.50                     -- link: wlo1

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 1.1292s.
-- Data is authenticated: no; Data was acquired via local or encrypted transport: yes
-- Data from: cache network

$ dig archlinux.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> archlinux.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60948
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;archlinux.com.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
archlinux.com.          7200    IN      A       3.64.163.50

;; Query time: 331 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 06 09:30:08 CEST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58


$ ss -tuna | grep :853
tcp   TIME-WAIT 0      0           192.168.0.112:48420        9.9.9.9:853
tcp   ESTAB     0      0           192.168.0.112:49032        9.9.9.9:853

The remaining question though is: Why do I get a different DNS on dnsleaktest.com?
Some things I tried:

sudo resolvectl flush-caches
sudo resolvconf -u
Put 9.9.9.9 only in the IPv4 DNS server list in NetworkManager
Put 127.0.0.53 only in the IPv4 DNS server list in NetworkManager
Added dns=none to the [main] sections of /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-dns-none.conf
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
reboot
Followed this guide which uses a simpler configuration: https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2022/04/enable-browsing-with-dns-over-tls-dot-on-ubuntu-made-easy.html
Following this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1069429/1780395, i.e.

cd /etc/
mv resolv.conf resolv.conf-old
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf


sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf. This results in:


$ ls -la /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr  8 09:10 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53

Nothing yet helped. Can you help me solving this?

It is a Desktop install and it is the entire output of resolvectl status. I just updated the main post accordingly.

Could it have to do something with a wrong link of /etc/resolv.conf?
The output of $ ls -la /etc/resolv.conf is
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr  6 09:39 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
This however is as expected by: sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf

I tested the suggestion from https://askubuntu.com/a/1069429/1780395:
cd /etc/
mv resolv.conf resolv.conf-old
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
The resolv.conf now looks different (no 127.0.0.53 anymore), but it didn't change anything.

The symlink for /etc/resov.conf by default is pointed to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf. You’ve now changed that. 127.0.0.53 is the local caching stub resolver.

How are you configuring your network interface?

Wrong assumption. I didn't change the link of /etc/resov.conf. As I described, I ran sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf. I added its output as screenshot, which acutally states /run/resolveconf/resolv.conf instead of /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf. I also added the resulting linked resolv.conf.
@mpboden Do you have a reference for the default?
Can you specify "How are you configuring"? I used the Kubuntu Network Manager GUI and only changed the DNS servers as described in my post.

This does not appear to be a DNS leak.
The IP address, 66.185.120.243 belongs to the WoodyNet, Inc. organization.
Here is the output of a Whois query for 66.185.120.243, which is listed in the output of your DNSLeak test:
#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/tou/
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/inaccuracy_reporting/
#
# Copyright 1997-2024, American Registry for Internet Numbers, Ltd.
#


NetRange:       66.185.112.0 - 66.185.127.255
CIDR:           66.185.112.0/20
NetName:        WOODYN
NetHandle:      NET-66-185-112-0-1
Parent:         NET66 (NET-66-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Allocation
OriginAS:       
Organization:   WoodyNet, Inc. (WOODYN)
RegDate:        2009-03-25
Updated:        2021-12-14
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/66.185.112.0


OrgName:        WoodyNet, Inc.
OrgId:          WOODYN
Address:        2351 Virginia St
City:           Berkeley
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     94709-1315
Country:        US
RegDate:        2001-05-16
Updated:        2022-04-28
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/WOODYN


OrgTechHandle: SHRES60-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Shrestha, Kabindra 
OrgTechPhone:  +1-415-831-3111 
OrgTechEmail:  email@pch.net
OrgTechRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/SHRES60-ARIN

OrgAbuseHandle: BW1324-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Woodcock, Bill 
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-415-831-3103 
OrgAbuseEmail:  email@pch.net
OrgAbuseRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/BW1324-ARIN

OrgTechHandle: BW1324-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Woodcock, Bill 
OrgTechPhone:  +1-415-831-3103 
OrgTechEmail:  email@pch.net
OrgTechRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/BW1324-ARIN


#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/tou/
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/inaccuracy_reporting/
#
# Copyright 1997-2024, American Registry for Internet Numbers, Ltd.
#

According to this post on SNB Forums, WoodyNet belongs to Quad9:

WoodyNet is Quad9. The Quad9.net homepage says it’s in collaboration
with Packet Clearinghouse (pch.net).

Looking at Quad9's website, it says the following:

Bill Woodcock - Chairman Bill is the executive director of Packet
Clearing House, the international non-governmental organization that
builds and supports critical Internet infrastructure, including
Internet exchange points and the core of the domain name system.

Referencing back to the Whois information, Bill Woodcock is listed as the contact for Abuse and Tech and the email addresses are email@pch.net, which is Packet Clearing House.
Furthermore, in the article, DNS To The Nines, at Medium, there is the following quote:

The easiest way to check is to run an online DNS leak test. When you
do so, you should see that the responding ISP is WoodyNet.
If you’re wondering why you’re seeing WoodyNet, it’s because Quad9 is
what’s called an anycast DNS, which automatically routes queries to
the nearest server. While Quad9 has servers at more than 100 locations
around the globe, it doesn’t own its own servers. Instead, Quad9
relies on Packet Clearing House (which is present at 160+ internet
exchange points) to host DNS servers for it. PCH’s Executive Director
is Bill Woodcock a/k/a Woody. Hence, WoodyNet.

And finally, the following is from a post on Y Combinator from someone claiming to be Bill Woodcock himself:

Hi. I'm Bill Woodcock, the eponymous "woody" of "woodynet." And
executive director of PCH, and chairman of Quad9's board. They are
three separate corporations, which exist for different reasons, and
under different tax regulations (PCH and Quad9 are public-benefit
not-for-profits, whereas WoodyNet exists to pay taxes on taxable
transactions and keep the non-profits' books clean), but they're very
closely related.
In this case, you're seeing WoodyNet IPs and IN-ADDRs because WoodyNet
is giving transit to the Quad9 anycast instance you're talking to.

At this point, I would reach out to Quad9 Support to confirm that this is not a DNS leak and that the server is theirs.
I reached out to quad9. They provided a link to Network Providers / DNS Leak Tests on their website that states the following:

Quad9 utilizes multiple network providers in our global network. When
running a DNS leak test, it's expected to see IP addresses owned by
the following providers:
Recommended DNS Leak Test Tool
dnscheck.tools
WoodyNet (AKA PCH.net)
PCH.net
GSL Networks
i3D
EdgeUno
Equinix Metal (FKA: Packet, Packet.net, or Packethost)
Path.net (Path Network)

These organizations are also listed on the Sponsors page of the Quad9
website: quad9.net/about/sponsors
If you are trying to simply determine if you are using Quad9, you can
visit on.quad9.net instead of relying on a DNS leak test. However, a
DNS leak test can be useful to ensure you're exclusively using Quad9,
which is required to ensure that all of your DNS requests will be
protected by Quad9.


Regarding your setup
By default /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf. The contents of this file indicate 127.0.0.53 as a nameserver. This is the local caching stub resolver.
You can verify this by downloading the Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS ISO, installing, and running the following command:
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf

The output will be:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Mar 20  2023 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

Next, resolvconf is not installed by default. So you or someone must have installed this package on your system. Using the same ISO as above and a fresh install, enter which resolvconf on the command line and it will return without any output. resolveconf is not necessary for you to do what you want to do.
If you look at your output of resolvectl status, take note of the following line in the Global section at the top:
resolv.conf mode: foreign

The value on this line is telling you something, which is what mode the /etc/resolv.conf file is using. There are four different modes of handling /etc/resolv.conf:

Mode 1 (stub): use stub resolver with search domains using symlink /etc/resolv.conf pointing to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

Mode 2 (static): use stub resolver without search domains using symlink /etc/resolv.conf pointing to /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf

Mode 3 (uplink): use uplink DNS nameservers using symlink /etc/resolv.conf pointing to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

Mode 4 (foreign): use static DNS nameservers by editing /etc/resolv.conf directly


From the man page for systemd-resolved:
/ETC/RESOLV.CONF         top

       Four modes of handling /etc/resolv.conf (see resolv.conf(5)) are
       supported:

       •   systemd-resolved maintains the
           /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf file for compatibility
           with traditional Linux programs. This file lists the
           127.0.0.53 DNS stub (see above) as the only DNS server. It
           also contains a list of search domains that are in use by
           systemd-resolved. The list of search domains is always kept
           up-to-date. Note that /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
           should not be used directly by applications, but only through
           a symlink from /etc/resolv.conf. This file may be symlinked
           from /etc/resolv.conf in order to connect all local clients
           that bypass local DNS APIs to systemd-resolved with correct
           search domains settings. This mode of operation is
           recommended.

       •   A static file /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf is provided that
           lists the 127.0.0.53 DNS stub (see above) as only DNS server.
           This file may be symlinked from /etc/resolv.conf in order to
           connect all local clients that bypass local DNS APIs to
           systemd-resolved. This file does not contain any search
           domains.

       •   systemd-resolved maintains the
           /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf file for compatibility with
           traditional Linux programs. This file may be symlinked from
           /etc/resolv.conf and is always kept up-to-date, containing
           information about all known DNS servers. Note the file
           format's limitations: it does not know a concept of
           per-interface DNS servers and hence only contains system-wide
           DNS server definitions. Note that
           /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf should not be used directly
           by applications, but only through a symlink from
           /etc/resolv.conf. If this mode of operation is used local
           clients that bypass any local DNS API will also bypass
           systemd-resolved and will talk directly to the known DNS
           servers.

       •   Alternatively, /etc/resolv.conf may be managed by other
           packages, in which case systemd-resolved will read it for DNS
           configuration data. In this mode of operation
           systemd-resolved is consumer rather than provider of this
           configuration file.

       Note that the selected mode of operation for this file is
       detected fully automatically, depending on whether
       /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
       or lists 127.0.0.53 as DNS server.

Because you've installed resolvconf, this application is now managing /etc/resolv.conf and is the reason the mode is listed as foreign in the output of resolvectl status.
When you ran sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf, the output indicated that a symlink would be created from /etc/resolv.conf that points to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf. This is where the default setup changed.

I'm not saying that this configuration is incorrect. Instead, I'm simply pointing out that it's not the default and that installing resolvconf is not needed.

This is a very thorough answer. Thank you very much!!!
